# Calculate Effective rate of the loan

Tags: percentages

Example: 10,000 EUR Interest Rate is: 6.96%, Additional payment 0.05% of the loan amount, and the effective loan rate is 7.34% says bank.

My question is, how did they come to 7.34% as the effective rate. What is the formula to calculate in excel.

Comment: How often is interest compounded?

Comment: 60 months. 12 a year

Answer (score 0):

I get this. You receive $9,995$ as loan proceeds but owe $10,000$.  So we compound the interest monthly on the 10K.  Here is what you owe at the end.

```
>>> owed = 10000*(1 + .0696/12)**12
>>> owed
10718.63730040249
```

Now divide out the loan proceeds as follows

```
>>> owed / 9995
1.0723999300052516
```

I get an effective rate of 7.24%.